# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning. Passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

Async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(), 
in this code line

```
async(req,email,password,done)=>{

    const user = await User.findOne({email:email});

    if (!user) {
        return done(null, false)
        //Err, no email found
    }

    if (!user.comparePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false);
        // Err, pass wrong
    }

    return done(null, user);
    // Login succesfull xd
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to do is...

```
async function login (email,password) {

    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({email});

      if (!user || !user.comparePassword(password)) {
        throw new Error('no user or wrong pass');
      }

      return user;
      // Login succesfull xd

    } catch (error) {
       // errors including any error thrown by await User.findOne 
       return null;
    }
}
```